# Different types of for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I have two types of for loops, `fileList` in this case is just a custom class that extends `AbstractList<Object>`

**1)** For loop iterating by index:

```
public String getExtensionByDescription(String description)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++)
        if (description.contains(fileList.get(i).getDescription()))
            return fileList.get(i).getExtension();
}
```

**2)** For loop iterating by item in list:

```
public String getExtensionByDescription(String description)
{
    for (FileType obj : fileList)
        if (description.contains(obj.getDescription()))
            return obj.getExtension();
}
```

Are method 1) and 2) logically the same or no? Because 1) returns the value i expect but method 2) returns the wrong value. Thanks for the help!

The implementation of list with various other get methods.

```
public class FileList extends AbstractList<Object>
{
    private ArrayList<FileType> fileList;

    public FileList()
    {
        fileList = new ArrayList<FileType>();
    }

    public void add(String search, String type, String extension, String description, String htmlicon)
    {

        FileType data = new FileType(fileList.size(), search, type, extension, description, htmlicon);
        if (!fileList.contains(data))
        {
        fileList.add(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index)
    {
        return fileList.toArray()[index];
    }
```

and the other class is

```
public FileType(int index, String search, String type, String extension, String description, String icon)
```

with function:

```
public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}
```

Comment: `AbstractList<Object>`?  What is the signature of `description.contains`?

Comment: Why extend a list class when you could just make an `ArrayList<FileType>` from the start?

Comment: I honestly, don't remember right now, there was a reason and i remember it being a good one but i'm going on 30hrs of coding right now and i can't remember. I just know i had to extend it and create custom get methods that i needed because i couldn't find FileType values otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was correct implementation of `List`, then they would be logically the same (although they could differ in terms of performance).

If they give different results then either `get(int)` method or `iterator()` method doesn't behave as expected, i.e. doesn't return `i`-th element or doesn't traverse through all elements respectively.

EDIT: After update of the question the issue is clear - you override `get(int)` method (although it returns Object but in the code it's accessed as FileType - looks suspicious). But there is no override of `iterator()` method. The `Iterator` which is returned by `iterator()` is actually used in the second for loop transparently by the compiler. Unless you override the code could never work.

Comment: I think it's a bit more subtle than that.  The fact that it's a list that uses `Object` as its backing type leads me to believe there's something else going on.

Comment: +1. Its also important to note that the second would support any `Collection`, allowing `FileList` to be changed to a `Set` or array without any changes to this code.

Comment: Sorry, so what do i need to do to fix this? Implement `Collections`? and create an overloaded `iterator`? What should my iterator be? @Makoto  I also removed the `<Object>`, now it is just an AbstractList and it works fine :S

Answer (score 0):

You may have a few things conflated here.

- Your enclosing class *also* had an iterator when all you wanted to do was iterate over your backing `ArrayList`.
- You overwrote `get`, which was guaranteed to give you back the result you wanted when using it, but didn't consider the `iterator()`.

Ultimately, there was no reason for you to extend `AbstractList` at all.  Just use the backing list instead.

To do that, create a getter for it:

```
public ArrayList<FileType> getFileList() {
    return fileList;
}
```

...and then use it in your iteration:

```
for(FileType type : fileList.getFileList()) {
    // logic here
}
```

It would then behave no differently to your `get`.